# Access cannot find the procedure which I just created

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a module in vba using the vbext_ct_StdModule object.

```
Set oMod = VBE.Activ eVBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
```

I then added a procedure to the code module using the AddFromString function.

```
oMod.CodeModule.AddFromString strVBScript
```

I then try to call the procedure which i have just created, and it doesn't work. I have tried both the call method and the application.run method.

After breaking out of the code, I am then able to run the procedure. I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to get around this?

Comment: I won't add as an answer as really have no idea if this will work - I generally don't change the design of a database once it's built.  The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/module-object-access) page says _Once you've returned a reference to a Module object, you can set or read its properties and apply its methods._.  So I guess something like `Dim mdl As Module: Set mdl = Modules![Utility Functions]: mdl.MyProcedureName`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your database before you can run functions.

You can try to compile the database by using the following `RunCommand`:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules
```

However, for that to work, the module has to be open in the VBE. You can open it using `DoCmd.OpenModule`, and close it after.