# how do i find out the current document component and code module parts

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, variable-assignment

I am trying to run the following code

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    StringExecute ("MsgBox ""hello""")
        
End Sub
Sub StringExecute(s As String)
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Set vbComp = ThisDocument.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString "Sub foo()" & vbCrLf & s & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
    Application.Run vbComp.Name & ".foo"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub
```

The problem is that I can't work out what to replace this document with. The code I am going to do is being used to convert a variable string to a command in Access VBA.  Ultimately, I will open up Microsoft Word in access and insert the data from the command into a word bookmark.

The most common error I get, or at least the closest I can get this to working, says that the property is not supported. Ultimately, I have got very close by swapping this document with the name of the Word document I intended using (oapp) in my case.  I then had to add .vbe after vbproject.

This at least allowed me to get past the set vbcomp line and debug.print suggested that vbcomp had set module 1 as the appropriate module.  However, when I hit the application.run line, it wouldn't find the .foo sub.  When I manually searched, I couldn't find where the add from string line had added anything (I did remove the last line, but it made no difference).

The following code is what I changed vbcomp to try to get somewhere.

```
    Set vbComp = Oapp.VBE.VBProjects.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    Debug.Print "the name of vbcomp is " & vbComp.Name
```

The problem seems to be (among other things, probably) that the code is trying to rewrite the module in word, instead of rewriting it in access.  Does anyone have any idea how to refer to the relevant component parts in access?

Comment: Would help to show the complete code you tried (eg what is `Oapp` above?)

Comment: This https://nolongerset.com/writing-code-with-code-in-vba/ plus this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709628/access-cannot-find-the-procedure-which-i-just-created perhaps.

Comment: You're complicating things for no reason by creating code-modules on-the-fly and then deleting them. Build your code in Access once and then call it from your main app. The code should remain the same, only the inputs should differ.